# Shopware6: Redirect the page after registering the customers in shopware 6

Tags: redirect, shopware6

How to redirect the page to the "Home page" after registering the customer programmatically.
Redirection should throw the "CustomerLoginEvent" not for the twig template.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the template `register.html.twig` and set the `redirectTo` variable.

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/account/register.html.twig' %}

{% block component_account_register_form %}
    {% if redirectTo == "frontend.account.home.page" %}
        {% set redirectTo = "frontend.home.page" %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for that guidance.
but I want to redirect by customer login through events.
can you help me?